# Spring Boot Wont Recover Mysql Connection

Tags: spring, spring-boot

If my Spring Boot app is left idle longer that the MySql `wait_timeout` it fails to create a new connection and the application is unusable.

```
2017-01-10 21:51:42.613 ERROR 26973 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : No operations allowed after connection closed.
2017-01-10 21:51:42.621 ERROR 26973 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: could not prepare statement; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: could not prepare statement] with root cause

java.io.EOFException: Can not read response from server. Expected to read 4 bytes, read 0 bytes before connection was unexpectedly lost
```

I have looked through many similar issues and added most of the recommendations but the problem still persists. I've tried dozens of combination of the lines below. The relevant parts of my application.properties are

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydb?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false

spring.datasource.log-validation-errors=true
spring.datasource.tomcat.testOnBorrow=true
spring.datasource.tomcat.timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis=30000
spring.datasource.tomcat.minEvictableIdleTimeMillis=60000
spring.datasource.tomcat.validationInterval=60000
spring.datasource.tomcat.validationQuery = SELECT 1
spring.datasource.tomcat.testWhileIdle=true
spring.datasource.tomcat.removeAbandoned=true
spring.datasource.tomcat.removeAbandonedTimeout=55
```

I've also tried the above lines without the tomcat namespace, but I believe that *.tomcat.* is correct for Spring Boot 1.4+. I've also tried snake case property names (e.g. test-while-idle).

I seems like the config is just being ignored.

I'm using

- Spring Boot 1.4.3
- Hibernate 5.2.6

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out. I was creating the Datasource in the Configuration class and manually setting some properties.

Removing that allowed it to work with only the following configuration properties

```
spring.datasource.tomcat.testWhileIdle = true
spring.datasource.tomcat.timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis = 30000
spring.datasource.tomcat.validationQuery = SELECT 1
```